# Nodejs internalyl call another endpoint without Axios and hitting middlewares of that endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, axios, backend

I have a scenario where I will have to register a business and create account for each directors of the business. So I should hit /auth/user api after /business post request is successful and send out the response to the user without waiting for the user account creation response. I have some features written in the middleware of /auth/user api for passport so I cannot make it as a separate function and call it internally to achieve this. I can achieve this by calling api endpoint using Axios, but I want to know if there is any better approach to achieve this. Appreciate any help here.

Comment: I am using Ts.ed platform